# Stop or hide loading panel when start an Ajax action

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, api

I have this portion of code globally to show the loading panel in my page.

```
$(document)
.ajaxStart(function () {
    $('#loadingPanel').fadeIn();
})
.ajaxStop(function () {
    $('#loadingPanel').fadeOut();
});
```

So, it will automatically show the loading panel anytime that I call an ajax action like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "localhost:8080/api/data/Test/GetData",
    success: doSomething
});
```

But just in a particular case I want to avoid displaying the loading panel. Is there a way to call the

```
$('#loadingPanel').hide();
```

within this code .ajax action or there's a workaround to avoid the loading panel for just some ajax actions instead of calling the fadeIn and fadeOut of each ajax action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `$.ajax(options)` you can set `global: false` in options to prevent [`.ajaxStart()`](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) from being triggered.

> [global](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
>   Whether to trigger global Ajax
>   event handlers for this request. The default is `true`. Set to `false` to
>   prevent the global handlers like
>   [`ajaxStart`](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) or
>   [`ajaxStop`](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) from being triggered.
>   This can be used to control various Ajax Events.